# I was in an infinite boot loop, so I reset and did a fresh install and I’m still stuck

Tags: windows, boot

Ever since I upgraded to windows 11 from 10 I noticed massive issues. Crashes, slower speeds everything. Eventually this morning it crashed and froze so I held the power button down to turn the computer off as this always saved the day, except it didn’t, it caused an infinite boot loop, after trying numerous things I eventually decided to just reset the computer with a fresh windows install from the windows recovery page. After this,I am not any closer into booting into windows. Just have that loading screen with the black background and white dots going in circles.

Comment: Everything you describe suggests a hardware problem

Answer (score 1):

So after extracting a windows 11 ISO onto an USB from my MacBook I reformatted my drive and installed it back into its original place and fixed my boot loop issue. I have reason to believe maybe my drives are coming to the end of their life mixed with a few issues with windows 11 maybe however I’m not too sure. So to prevent it in the future I will buy a new drive or two just to be on the safe side. I believe a crash caused corrupted files and stopped me from booting. And maybe the crash in the first place was due to the drive not windows itself.

Answer (score 0):

> I eventually decided to just reset the computer with a fresh windows
> install from the windows recovery page.

The reset you did probably did not delete the User Profile. If that is a problem, reset will not cure it.

Run the Microsoft PC Health Check also. Run from bootable USB.

Best, when the Windows 10 - Windows 11 upgrade fails, to back everything up and install Windows 11 completely fresh.